# Conflict between click, mouseenter and toggleclass, remove background colour onclick

Tags: jquery, html, mouseenter, mouseleave

This is how my code works:

1. This is how it looks like originally.
   [image]
2. After click the first thumbnail image (show in red box), the blue colour background is activated.
   [image]
3. When click the 2nd thumbnail image (show in red box), the blue colour background is activated also.
   [image]
4. My problem is here. When I click the same image to close the expander, the blue colour background is still showing there. **I want remove it when expander is closed**.
   [image]

This is part of my code, my code is too long. I just took the simplified part. I think my jQuery has some issues, but I'm not sure how to change it, hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.thumbnail').mouseenter(function(e) {
  $(this).children('span').children('span').removeClass('title');
  $(this).children('span').children('span').addClass('dark-background').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(500);
 }).mouseleave(function(e) {
  $(this).children('span').children('span').removeClass('dark-background').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(200);
  $(this).children('span').children('span').addClass('title');  //click and just remove title
 });

 $(".thumbnail").click(function(){ 
  $(".thumbnail").children('span').children('span').removeClass("background-active"); 
  $(this).children('span').children('span').toggleClass('background-active');     
 });
});
```

```css
.gallery-item {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.gallery-item .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.gallery-contents { position: relative; }

.gallery-item .title {
 position:absolute; 
 bottom:0px; 
 left:0px;
 width:50%;
 background-color:#5ba4ee;
 color:#fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}


.dark-background, .background-active {
 background-color: rgba(112, 158, 202, 0.8);
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 50%;
 padding-top: 30%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 50%;
 z-index: 100;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.background-active.title {
 background-color: rgba(112, 158, 202, 0.8);
 padding-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-item">
  <div class="gallery-contents">
    <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger">
      <span>
        <span class="title">Gallery Item</span>
        <img src="https://cdn-main.123contactform.com/images3/landing_pages/free-small-business-forms.png" alt="" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-contents">
    <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger">
      <span>
        <span class="title">Gallery Item</span>
        <img src="https://cdn-main.123contactform.com/images3/landing_pages/free-small-business-forms.png" alt="" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.thumbnail').mouseenter(function(e) {
  $(this).children('span').children('span').removeClass('title');
  $(this).children('span').children('span').addClass('dark-background').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(500);
 }).mouseleave(function(e) {
  $(this).children('span').children('span').removeClass('dark-background').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(200);
  $(this).children('span').children('span').addClass('title');  //click and just remove title
 });

 $(".thumbnail").click(function(){ 
    $(".thumbnail").not(this).children('span').children('span').removeClass("background-active");  
  $(this).children('span').children('span').toggleClass('background-active');  
 });
});
```

```css
.gallery-item {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.gallery-item .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.gallery-contents { position: relative; }

.gallery-item .title {
 position:absolute; 
 bottom:0px; 
 left:0px;
 width:50%;
 background-color:#5ba4ee;
 color:#fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}


.dark-background, .background-active {
 background-color: rgba(112, 158, 202, 0.8);
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 50%;
 padding-top: 30%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 50%;
 z-index: 100;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.background-active.title {
 background-color: rgba(112, 158, 202, 0.8);
 padding-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-item">
  <div class="gallery-contents">
    <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger">
      <span>
        <span class="title">Gallery Item</span>
        <img src="https://cdn-main.123contactform.com/images3/landing_pages/free-small-business-forms.png" alt="" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-contents">
    <div class="thumbnail gallery-trigger">
      <span>
        <span class="title">Gallery Item</span>
        <img src="https://cdn-main.123contactform.com/images3/landing_pages/free-small-business-forms.png" alt="" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just use `.not(this)` to exclude it from removing the `background-active`.

Comment: Cool! Only add ".not(this)", I really not familiar with jQuery :(

Comment: @Eelyn I'm glad I was able to help :)